ModuleNotFoundError: apt_pkg
I am trying to install Python in my EC2 instance
using these commands:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install python3.12 

However, upon running the first command, I received this prompt:

Solutions I tried but did not fix the problem:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt 
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so 
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-apt 

Would appreciate any help at all!

deb packages are built for specific releases, and currently we don't know yours, thus are limited in what we can provide. Does the PPA support your unstated release? Did you read messages for clues?  (we're limited to details you provided, which currently isn't much).  You provided a picture of an actual error, but as we don't know your OS/release we can't interpret what you provided; thus you'll need to once you work out what you're running  (does your default python3 version match your release? have you .. etc).
